# Regex capturing group to match any URL with a capital letter

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a regex that would match a URL with at least one capital letter into a capturing group.

**Example:**

`/Hello-WoRLD` would match

`/hellO/WoRld` would match

`/foo/hello-WorLd/bar/baz/` would match

`/this/url/is-in/all-lowercase` would NOT match

Basically any number of slugs with at least one capital letter would match.

I have the following regex that match for just one slug

`^\/([a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*)\/?$`

But cant figure out how to match an indefinite number of slugs into the capturing group.

For context, I would rewrite this URL as `/$1` to effectively rewrite all URL with capital letters to their lowercase counterparts.

Comment: *But cant figure out how to match an indefinite number of slugs into the capturing group.* - you can't, each subsequent capture rewrites the group memory buffer.

Comment: but if my single capturing group matches the `/slug1/slug2/slug3/..` pattern, the whole thing will be matched, no?

Comment: Is this part of some rewrite rule? You can probably use: `^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```perl
^.*[A-Z].*$
```

And use `\L$0` as the replacement.

https://regex101.com/r/aIqiKf/1

Comment: You probably just mean `^.*[A-Z].*$`, although `^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*$` will be more efficient. Not sure it actually helps OP.

Comment: why `\L$0` and not `\L$1`? Also looks like you need parenthesis around the whole thing to capture the group: `^(.*(?=[A-Z]).*)$`

Comment: @yevg Do you know what `$0` does?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I do not

Comment: @yevg I'll give you a few minutes to look it up then.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "$0 matches entire string. $1 is the first subpattern" ok gochya!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right, really not sure why I chose to use the lookahead so I'll steal your suggestion if that's alright. `^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*$` might be a bit too cryptic for future (or current) readers of OP's system.